# Transfer file (.txt) between apps

Tags: android, android-intent, share, data-import

An application is exporting a text (.txt) file when shared through it, I can see apps like Gmail, Dropbox, drive, share it etc to share it through that app. I want to import that text file in my application for further modification of that. txt file.
What should I implement in manifest or main activity?
Should I use **`INTENT`** filter or should I use **`getUriForFile()`** method to receive the text file?
How will my app appear in other apps sharing list which export text files?. [image: export form whatsapp][image: send chat via...][image: share text file from file explorer][image: whatsapp extract my app is visible]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following  `intent-filter` for importing any file from another application into your manifest

```
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
```

Then use below code in your activity for getting URI for a text file

```
    private Uri getUriForFile() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();
    if (TextUtils.equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND, action) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(type)) {

        Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        if (uri != null) {
            Log.e("uri",uri.toString());
            return  uri;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

> UPDATE

if the activity is your launcher activity then use the following  intent filter

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Sir I am exporting chat from whatsapp but the after implementing this still my application is not visbile int the export option. but my file explorer is (saying copy to). and when i copy that i realized its storing in a .txt file. but my application isnt visible on whatsapp.

Comment: I am getting  message (send chat via bluetooth, shareit, gmail, or even copy to explorer) but my app is  not visibile

Comment: I edited my answer .Its working for me. Please add your manifest file . then only I can Understand more . And also please tell me which device you are using

Comment: <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/> worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to associate your application with a file extension, for that do this:

```
<data android:scheme="file" /> //Means local file
<data android:mimeType="*/*"/> //This accept any mimeType
<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" /> //Your excepted extention
```

After that open your `Manifest` and  add this lines too(You have to add an intent filter to your destination activity):

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Hope this can helps you.

Comment: for path pattern a host must be specified

Comment: No, You just have to put this intentFilter into your activity that has to contract with textFiles.